# Java FX change Halignment of Component

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, alignment, fxml

```
public CheckBox createBox(){
    CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
    box.setText(name);
    box.setOnMouseClicked(x -> handlePlaying(box));
    return box;
}
```

than I add them to a GridPane

```
checkBoxes
            .forEach(x -> gridPane.add(x, checkBoxes.indexOf(x) + 1, 2));
```

Now I want to change the Halignment, but I can't find the method.

PS: I Want to Change the Halignement not the general Alignement;

Comment: This depends what container the component is in... please could you post self contained example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this example illustrates the differences between Labelled.setAlignment() and GridPane.setHAlignment().

[image: alignment]

Code

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    CheckBox box1 = new CheckBox("horse");
    box1.setMinWidth(200);
    box1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    grid.getChildren().add(box1);
    CheckBox box2 = new CheckBox("banana");
    grid.getChildren().add(box2);
    GridPane.setRowIndex(box2, 1);
    GridPane.setHalignment(box2, HPos.RIGHT);   // <=== this is probably what you want
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I'd recommend FXML over programmatic layout, but same principles apply. Find the HAlignment property in Layout tab in SceneBuilder...

Labelled.setAlignment() does explain this already in its JavaDoc, although I can see why this might be confusing.

> Specifies how the text and graphic within the Labeled should be
>   aligned when there is empty space within the Labeled.